# where is .so file saved in android

Tags: android, shared-libraries

assume my application needed a library to work. this library has .so file in raw folder. it seems first time I run application this .so file saved somewhere on android device because when I delete this .so file form library , application run without any problem, but I want to test application for some reason and I need to delete this .so file but I can't find it. anybody know where .so file saved on android?

Comment: `.so` goes in `libs/armeabi`

Comment: where is libs folder?